# Change all Row Values by X in a formula in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to change all Row Values in a formula e.g.

```
=E21+F21+E120+F120+E219+F219+E318+F318+E417+F417
```

(Increase all Row Values by 3) =

```
=E23+F23+E123+F123+E222+F222+E321+F321+E420+F420
```

Comment: Copy that formula down two rows? (and the cut and paste it back... if needed)

Comment: Good input. But in this case I am rearranging some data so I can't rely on that method because the data is not streamlined yet

Comment: Probably best to mention that in your question, then I'll delete my comments :)

Comment: insert two rows and drag formula down, then copy formula and delete extra rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the formula in let's say cell `A1`

then drag the Fill Handle(Bottom Right Point of selected cell) till `A4`
Then in Cell `A4`, you will have your formula with cell numbers incremented by 3.

Comment: To complete your description: "*Then copy that formula in A4 as text (not the cell). Press undo and paste it in A1.*" And this only works if the formula in A1 does not reference any cell from A2 to A4. But as workaround for this you can *move* the cell A1 to any empty place eg. move form A1 to AAA1 then perform the above actions (pull down ta AAA4, copy, paste back) and then move it back from AAA1 to A1